# How to use dlmwrite in matlab to export pixels in R,G,B format?

Tags: matlab

Right now when I export my image using dlmwrite:

```
dlmwrite('testy2.txt', A, 'delimiter', '\t')
```

I get something like this

```
0   31  255 251 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

This is difficult to work with and visualize and I was wondering if there was a way to separate this into the format:

```
0,31,255    251,255,255    255,255,255  255,255,255    255,255,255
```

with tabs in between each R,G,B value

How do I do this either when I'm exporting in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `fprintf` rather than `dlmwrite` to create a custom output like that. We can use the format specification of `%d,%d,%d\t` to create three numbers separated by a comma followed by a tab and this will be repeated for all values in `A`.

```
fid = fopen('testy2.txt', 'w');

fprintf(fid, '%d,%d,%d\t', A);

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Drej if this worked for you please consider marking it as the solution.